# Compiling Glossaries with neovim

Tags: compiling, glossaries

I am using vimtex with the following vim.init setup:

```
let g:Tex_FormatDependency_pdf = 'dvi,ps,pdf'

let g:Tex_CompileRule_dvi = '~/mnt/d/MikTeX/miktex/bin/x64/pdflatex.exe --interaction=nonstopmode $*'
let g:Tex_CompileRule_ps = 'dvips -Ppdf -o $*.ps $*.dvi'
let g:Tex_CompileRule_pdf = 'ps2pdf $*.ps'


let g:Tex_FormatDependency_pdf = 'dvi,ps,pdf'
```

I am trying to compile a file that has a glossary. So something like:

```
\documentclass[10pt,letterpaper,final]{article}
\usepackage{glossaries}
\makeglossaries
\newglossaryentry{tplgy:topology}{
    name ={Topology},
    description = {Topology}    
}
\begin{document}
\glsaddall
\printglossaries
\end{document}
```

This however produces a blank page. I think the issue is that the compiler has to run an extra time to properly construct the glossary, but I am not sure what to change in the init.vim file to make that happen.

Comment: This question was [crossposted on Vi and Vim SE](https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/44277/setting-up-neovim-to-compile-glossaries-in-latex).